# p-type and n-type solids

Tags: current, semiconductors, pn-junction

Is the difference between p-type and n-type solids simply the difference in the placement of the valence and conductive band in the solid. Otherwise I fail to understand, p-type means lots of holes and the electrons move towards the holes as the holes attract the electrons. n-type means lots of electrons and the electrons move towards the holes because they attract the holes? I am confused by this.

Comment: I've edited the tags on your question. I think [semiconductors] is very relevant here. And I removed [electricity] and [charge] because I don't think they'll help people who can answer this question find it.

Comment: This wikipedia article on doping in semiconductors might be a place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_%28semiconductor%29.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being I would forget about electron and hole movement/attraction, and consider simply how many electrons and holes there are. *P*-type and *n*-type materials are not determined by the position of the bands as such, more so defined by the 'majority carrier' in the material, *i.e.* in an *n*-type semiconductor the material has been doped by additional electrons, thus the population of electrons is higher than that of holes. In a *p*-type material, an 'acceptor' has been added to mop up electrons, thus holes become the majority carrier.

Another thing you may want to consider is the position of the Fermi level - the hypothetical energy level which has a 50% chance of being occupied. In an *n*-type semiconductor, as a result of the additional electrons that come through doping, higher energy levels become occupied. This means that the Fermi level also rises to be closer to the conduction band. The opposite is true for *p*-type materials.